# Find differences in mysql table and query

Tags: mysql

I hope I can explain this correctly. Here it is:

I have a list of id's that I need to check in a mysql table against a subscription status to find out how many of those id's are current. I have the id and the subscriptionEnd. My query is not working and I do not have enough knowledge to know how this would be done. Please review and share with me what I could do. There are thousands of id's I need to match against.

```
SELECT c.id, c.subscriptionEnd
FROM subscriptions c
WHERE c.subscriptionEnd > '2013-01-27`
AND c.id = 12345
AND c.id = 12939
....
```

This list goes on and on and I see that this will not work. But the problem is I don't know how to get this to work. Very much appreciated with any solutions on how I can check and get the results of the id's that have a subscriptionEnd greater than the date given.

Thank you

Comment: I assume you mean `OR` between those ids...`AND` will never be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet, since you have 1000's of values to check against, is to insert all of the ids you want to check into a temporary table - let's call the table `checkIds` with a single column `id`.

Then you can simply do:

```
SELECT c.id, c.subscriptionEnd
FROM subscriptions c
INNER JOIN checkIds ON c.id = checkIds.id
WHERE c.subscriptionEnd > '2013-01-27'
```

And finally drop the temporary table when you are done.

---

Other solutions include:

- A giant unwieldy `IN` clause which will probably be a performance nightmare:

  ```
  SELECT c.id, c.subscriptionEnd
  FROM subscriptions c
  WHERE c.subscriptionEnd > '2013-01-27'
  AND c.id IN (12345, 12939, ...)
  ```
- Finding a pattern in your list of IDs:

  ```
  SELECT c.id, c.subscriptionEnd
  FROM subscriptions c
  WHERE c.subscriptionEnd > '2013-01-27'
  AND (c.id = 12345
      OR c.id BETWEEN 12939 AND 12951
      OR ...)
  ```

Comment: Perfect with the temporary table. Thank you